# AsyncTask vs Service on data synchronization from remote server

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I've been building medium sized information systems for a year now, using Android as one of the client-side, but I have never used a `Service` before. To request data from the server, I always fire a request using `AsyncTask`. When the user enter the corresponding `Activity`.

A diagram might be represented by the following:

```
                    -> fires -> AsyncTask -> request from network and insert into local -> refresh view
Activity#onCreate() 
                    -> query local database -> refresh view
```

Since `AsyncTask` executes on a background thread, there are no bug issues or similar.

Can I get a REAL explanation on `Services` vs `AsyncTask` on network operations?

Comment: My bad, I didn't found that one when looking, it is indeed a duplicate

Comment: No problem. it's a common question and there are several really good articles on it.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a long running background task such as connecting to a socket and want it to live even if you start another app you need **service**, and if you just download, get, etc from a server(except downloading a large file) for a short period of time then you should use **AsyncTask**..

well in your diagram it is a short running background task where AsyncTask is best fitted for it.